# Email host rewritten by sendmail/postfix

Tags: postfix, sendmail

I have a Postfix mail server running, and I'm trying to understand why emails sent to `myself@example.com` are actually sent to `myself@some-server.example.com` instead.

On the command line, I send a simple test email:

```
echo test | mail -s test myself@example.com
```

In `maillog`, I see:

> Mar 20 23:40:57 some-server sendmail[29680]: r2L3euXm029680: from=root,
>   size=48, class=0, nrcpts=1,
>   msgid=<201303210340.r2L3euXm029680@some-server.example.com>,
>   relay=root@localhost

So I understand that sendmail is used to send the email, and my Postfix server will receive it.

I enabled the verbose option in Postfix, so I have pretty long logs, but the part that strike me as wrong is this:

```
Mar 20 23:40:57 some-server postfix/smtpd[29681]: < localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]: MAIL From:<root@some-server.example.com> SIZE=48 AUTH=root@some-server.example.com
Mar 20 23:40:57 some-server postfix/smtpd[29681]: > localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]: 250 2.1.0 Ok
Mar 20 23:40:57 some-server postfix/smtpd[29681]: < localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]: RCPT To:<myself@some-server.example.com>
```

So the From part is OK; I'm testing from root, and the machine hostname is `some-server.example.com`, but who changed the `TO` email address from `myself@example.com` to `myself@some-server.example.com`?

From what I understand from the log, that last line is a command received by Postfix from sendmail. So why is sendmail saying I want to send to that address, when I asked for something else on the command line?

This returns nothing but comments:

```
grep -ri some-server /etc/mail /etc/postfix
```

I also tried to send emails to `potato@example.com`, and it also gets rewritten as `potato@some-server.example.com`, so the problem is with the host, not the user, getting re-written.

I'll be happy to provide more logs if needed. Just let me know what to try and what logs would be useful to understand what is happening.

Thanks.

**Edit #1**:

If I try `sendmail -bt`, and enter `check_mail <myself@example.com>`, I get this:

```
...
Canonify2          input: myself < @ example . com >
Canonify2        returns: myself < @ some-server . example . com . >
...
```

Not sure what that means.

**Edit #2**:

I read somewhere that domains re-writing could be cause by a wildcard MX entry in the domain. I indeed had that, and have since removed it. It didn't resolve the problem, but maybe there is a delay in the propagation (even if dig seems to indicate propagation is now complete).

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem was DNS entries.

I removed the wildcard `MX` I had, I created a `MX` for `some-server.example.com`, and also changed the @ `CNAME` I had for `example.com` for a `A` record, and now Sendmail works without rewriting my hostname.